# Why does Apple use ContiguousArray in the implementation of Sequence.map?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, optimization, foundation

Why Apple first creates `ContiguousArray`, then fills it to `initialCapacity` and then checks that everything is filled and converts the result to `Array`.

Why not just create an `Array` at once and fill it as you go through the original array?

https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a0d52344bb457e3443ca5d164b65fd940db67744/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L673

```
  @inlinable
  public func map<T>(
    _ transform: (Element) throws -> T
  ) rethrows -> [T] {
    let initialCapacity = underestimatedCount

    // ??
    var result = ContiguousArray<T>()
    result.reserveCapacity(initialCapacity)

    var iterator = self.makeIterator()

    // ?? Add elements up to the initial capacity without checking for regrowth. ??
    for _ in 0..<initialCapacity {
      result.append(try transform(iterator.next()!))
    }

    // Add remaining elements, if any.
    while let element = iterator.next() {
      result.append(try transform(element))
    }
    return Array(result)
  }
```

Comment: Most probably for performance reasons, but no one can answer for sure other than the people who actually wrote that code. If you look at the docs for [ContiguousArray](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/contiguousarray), they do claim that for `@objc` elements, it might be more performant than a regular `Array`. `reserveCapacity` might also avoid unnecessary reallocations, so when working with a known number of elements in a performance critical environment, doing that rather than dynamically allocating the capacity might be beneficial.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I would think perforce reasons too and not necessarily just to avoid unnecessary allocations. Returning an array that is guaranteed contiguous (assuming it is) is probably advantageous e.g. for cache locality.

Comment: This post's question and body don't quite match. Are you asking why they use `ContiguousArray` at all, or why they do this dance with `underestimatedCount`, a `for` loop and a `while` loop? Could you please edit your question to clarify?

Comment: @Alexander, i think the this implementation details "why they do this dance with `underestimatedCount`, a `for` loop and a `while` loop?" depends on why apple used ContiguousArray in their source, therefore i ask main question about  `ContiguousArray` and then fleshing out the question in the body.

Answer (score 1):

This will make more sense once you understand the underpinning of arrays. (In the simple case) Arrays are wrappers around a pointer to a contiguous heap-allocated buffer.

That buffer has a limited capacity, dictated by the amount of memory allocated for its exclusive use. Appending new elements is very fast and cheap while there's capacity (it just involves filling in the value, and increment the `count`), but at some point you hit the end. At that point, you can't just keep appending (you'll overrun your allocated space, and start overwriting other objects' memory!), so room needs to be made. If you're lucky, you can have `realloc` expand your allocation in-place, if there happens to be nothing allocated past the end of your buffer (it can then just give that extra capacity to you).

But in the likely case that this direct reallocation fails, the Array has no choice but to allocate a new larger buffer, and copy over the contents of its old buffer, before it can then just add in the new element. This is the slow part, that we'd like to do as rarely as possible.

1. One extreme is to only make the new buffer whose capacity is only 1 element higher. This minimizes wasted memory (waste = over-allocation of capacity that never ultimately gets used), but is horrible for performance (every `append` triggers a full copy!).
2. One the other extreme is to ask for a radically larger buffer than likely will be necessary. This will have plenty of room for new elements, minimize copies, but it'll obviously waste a ton of space.

Somewhere in the middle is a sweat spot, where you over-allocate just enough capacity so as to minimize copies, but not so much that you waste tons of memory. Growing by 1.5x every time is a common strategy, and I think it's the one Swift uses.

So based on these ideas, you can see why it's a bad idea to blindly repeatedly append into an empty array. If you can ask for a right-size array from the start (with `reserveCapacity`), that can be a large benefit, but that's not always possible (e.g. in an implementation of `filter`, you don't usually have a general way to guess how many of the elements of `self` will end up in the result).

What you're seeing in Apple's code here is a two stage approach:

1. Reserve enough space for the sequence's `underestimatedCount`. Fill it with that many elements. Since this is an underestimation, there will be some more left over.
2. Continue and fill in the remaining elements with repeaded `appends`.

Sequence's `underestimatedCount` is central to this. In the general case, sequences don't have a well-known size up-front (there's even infinite sequences, like `1...`), but `underestimatedCount` exists to provide a good first guess.

You can contrast this with `Collection`, which has a well-known `count` that can be used to allocate the exact right size result array from the get-go.